# Azure CLI Tool Fails to List Resources on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, devops, azure-cli, ubuntu-21.04

I installed the Azure command line utility for Ubuntu using Microsoft's official instructions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-linux?pivots=apt

I was able to authenticate with Azure, but now I'm having issues listing resources:

```
 $ az resource list
```

My results were an error:

```
CLIInternalError: The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
API version 2020-10-01 does not have operation group 'resources'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/knack/cli.py", line 233, in invoke
    cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 659, in execute
    raise ex
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 722, in _run_jobs_serially
    results.append(self._run_job(expanded_arg, cmd_copy))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 715, in _run_job
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 693, in _run_job
    result = cmd_copy(params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 330, in __call__
    return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/azure/cli/core/__init__.py", line 786, in default_command_handler
    return op(**command_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/resource/custom.py", line 2015, in list_resources
    resources = rcf.resources.list(filter=odata_filter, expand=expand)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/azure/mgmt/resource/resources/_resource_management_client.py", line 396, in resources
    raise ValueError("API version {} does not have operation group 'resources'".format(api_version))
ValueError: API version 2020-10-01 does not have operation group 'resources'
To open an issue, please run: 'az feedback'
```

Comment: Can you try with an older version? BTW, what version doy ou have? [Here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/13331#issuecomment-635446175) you can find instruction how to install older version.

Comment: Hi, any update on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to [update Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/update-azure-cli) to the latest version and try again.

If it still does not work, you could use the [`az rest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az_rest) as below to call the REST API directly, it does the same thing with `az resource list`.

```
az rest --method get --url https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resources?api-version=2021-04-01
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to be to purge the Ubuntu packages and to install azure via pypi using pip:

```
 $ pip install azure-cli
```

Then az just worked.

https://pypi.org/project/azure-cli/